# Discord.py bad messages are deleting other messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have it so my bot deletes and message with a bad word in it. For some reason if I do 2 bad words in a row, it deletes the first message and dm's me once, then deletes 2 other messages and dm's me twice. Can some tell me what im doing wrong?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    bad_words = ['bad','bot']
    user = client.get_user(647589407515213866)
    for word in bad_words:
        if (message.content.count(word) > 0) and (message.content.count(word) < 2):
            print("A bad word was said")
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
            await user.send(f'User {message.author} wrote {word}')
        else:
            await client.process_commands(message)
```

Can someone tell me why its stacking up messages and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  should use `message.delete` instead of purging from the channel.  Instead of deleting a message for every bad word, you should delete the message if it is true for any bad word.  We can use a `for` loop with an `else` clause:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    bad_words = ['bad','bot']
    user = client.get_user(647589407515213866)
    for word in bad_words:
        if 0 < message.content.count(word) < 2:
            print("A bad word was said")
            await user.send(f'User {message.author} wrote {word}')
            await message.delete()
            break
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Also, greater than 0 and less than 2 is just 1, so you could check for that.

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question. How would I get the exact word that the user said. If I try to use "word", it says its not a variable. If I do message.content, it sends me a dm for the number of bad words. I want to dm the user the specific word that was said. How would I do that.

Comment: Oh, I missed that.  In that case, you will have to have a for loop over the words.  We'll just exit the loop when we find a word

Comment: Thank you very much!